# Сокеты в Java

Tags: java, сокет

Нужен хелп по созданию примитивного клиент-серверного приложения. Сам что-то разобраться не в силах=( Если можно ссылочку на почитать. Желательно на русском.Спасибо=)

Comment: @altvirus Поясните, что именно у Вас не получается.

Comment: Скажите, именно какой скрипт нужен??

Comment: Какой скрипт? Вы о чём? На Java не пишут скрипты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Пример](http://www.cs.swan.ac.uk/~csneal/InternetComputing/JavaSockets.html), что не понятно - спрашивайте.
[На русском](http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/java/sockets.php), но по-моему уж очень просто.